# Alternative to chi-squared goodness-of-fit test for very small sample size

Tags: chi-squared-test

I have a question similar to the ones described in the forum here (http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/chi-square-goodness-of-fit-test-in-r).

I want to know whether one sex is more common than the other at a study site. Unfortunately, I am dealing with a very cryptic species and my sample size is less than 5 for each sex for a particular year.(male = 5, female = 3).

If I were to perform a chi-squared GOF test, my code would be as follows:

```
    sex.ratio = chisq.test(c(5,3), p = c(0.5,0.5))
```

Is there an alternative to the Chi-squared GOF Test that would be appropriate to run on this dataset with very small sample sizes?

Comment: Welcome to CV!  Such a test would be pointless, because the dataset is too small to conclude anything.  But what distinction are you making between "a chi-squared test" and "the Chi-squared GOF test"?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I specified GOF test, because I am dealing with expected probabilities and not counts.

Comment: You use two different phrases to refer to these tests: do they mean the same thing or not?  Regardless, *no* test is about counts.  All hypothesis tests are about inherent properties of the distribution, not about the data.

Comment: I meant the same thing, but as far as R coding goes, it's chisq.test(observed_vector_count, p = expected_probability_vector) for GOF test, and chisq.test(matrix) for test of independence (not what I am interested in)

Comment: @Rnoobie Your question is quite unclear, because the R code you give *is* a chi-squared goodness-of-fit test, but just after that you ask how to conduct it. It looks like you're misinterpreting what a goodness-of-fit test is, or that you are omitting some information necessary for us to understand your question.

Comment: I am asking if there is a similar test but for very small sample sizes. Because all the stats forums I have read mention I should not use chi-squared gof test if the sample size is <5. I came across Yates correction and Fisher's exact test, but they do not work the same way as chi-squared gof test. Anyway, it seems pointless to try and do any test with such a small sample size (which I already knew, but was hoping someone here would have other suggestions.)

Comment: @Rnoobie I see. I suggested an edit to the question to make it a bit less ambiguous.

Comment: You can use a straight one sample binomial test of proportions (conditioning on the total count), but as whuber explained at the start, it really doesn't matter what test you would choose, the sample size is too small. If you want to use some $\alpha$ that's below 9/128 (ie. anything smaller than $\alpha=7.03125\%$), no reasonable two-sided test can be significant unless the split is 8-0 or 0-8 (that would be significant at the 1% level).

Answer (score 6):

Because the counts are small, you might use an exact binomial test:

```
binom.test(5, 8)
```

or a chi-square test with Monte Carlo simulation

```
chisq.test(c(5, 3), simulate.p.value=TRUE, B=10000)
```

However, think about the the meaning of the *p*-value in this case.  It's analogous to flipping a coin 8 times (with the null hypothesis being that the coin is fair, with a 50/50 probability of getting heads).  If you flip the coin 8 times, would it be that surprising to get 5 heads even if the coin is fair ?